# Rails: How can I edit text files stored on Amazon S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm using [paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to upload some text/csv files to an S3 bucket.

I need to edit those files occasionally. How can I edit and re-save those?

Before using S3, I was just using `File.open` for saving the files, but that throws a "No such file or directory" error now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.open` opens a file system object.  To access S3 you need to connect to the S3 server and issue commands, such as GET.

There are some gems available from the Amazon developer's site which may help.

http://aws.amazon.com/ruby/